# ubuntu 18.04 black remote screen

Tags: ubuntu, display, remote-desktop

I would like to use the main display of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Anydesk without an attached monitor. How can I do that ?
When i try to connect if there is no monitor on I get a black screen.
I tried to use a lot of vnc software but I cannot get what I want.

thanks
best regards

Comment: You need either a dummy dongle (google it) or to create a virtual display (also google it).

Comment: ok thnaks, but if i set a virtual display then when if a turn on the monitor i see another one... I would to see always the same